# Regex Capturing Group with alternative doesn't match

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I have the following string where I want to match the valid `<key>:<value>` pairs.

A valid `<key>` is anything with a non-whitespace character followed by `:`
A valid `<value>` is either enclosed in `[]` or a string without whitespaces.

```
key1:value1 key#2:@value#2 nyet key3:[@value#3, value4] key4:[value5] :bar
```

Basically I want to match everything except `nyet` and `:bar`

I came up with following regex `\S+:(\S+|\[[^]]+\])` but it doesn't seem to match the expression in `key3:[@value#3, value4]`. In the capturing group, the second alternative `\[[^]]+\]` should match this expression, so I don't understand why it doesn't match.

The following regex works: `\S+:([^([ )]+|\[[^\]]+\])` but doesn't feel elegant.

Questions:

1. Why does the first regex `\S+:(\S+|\[[^]]+\])` not work?
2. How would a more elegant solution look to match the key value pairs?

Comment: Probably, `([^\s:]+):(?|\[([^][]*)]|(\S+))` will suit your scenario, but it requires PCRE/Boost. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EzAToB/1).

Comment: Your first regex does not work because `\S+` alternative is put first. It always "wins" since `[` is also a non-whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern you can [switch the alternatives](https://regex101.com/r/n1vxd8/1) `\S+:(\[[^]]+\]|\S+)` but is would also match the `[]` in that case.

You could also [exclude](https://regex101.com/r/nQizsN/1) matching the `:` in the first part `[^\s:]+:(\[[^]]+]|\S+)` using a negated character class.

For the groups, you could use an alternation and check for the existence of group 2 or group 3 for the value.

```
([^\s:]+):(?:\[([^][]+)]|(\S+))
```

The pattern matches:

- `([^\s:]+)` Capture **group 1**, match any char except a whitespace char or `:`
- `:` Match the `:`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[([^][]+)]` Match `[` capture in **group 2** any char except `[` and `]` and match the closing `]`
  - `|` or
  - `(\S+)` Capture 1+ non whitespace chars in **group 3**
- `)` Close non capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Mk4Ya/1)

---

If an [conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) is supported, you could check if group 2 has captured a `[`. If it did, you can capture any char except the brackets in group 3.

The values you want are then in group 1 and group 3.

```
([^\s:]+):(?:(\[)(?=[^][]*]))?((?(2)[^][]+|\S+))\]?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0SkJhK/1)

Answer (score 1):

1. You were close with your regex. It failed because the `:\S` had precedence over `:\[`
2. This regex works:

```
/\S+:(?:\[[^\]]*\]|\S+)/g
```

Explanation:

- `\S+:` - 1+ non-space chars and a colon
- `(?:` - non-capturing group start (for OR)

  - `\[[^\]]*\]` - `[...]` pattern
  - `|` - logical OR
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-space chars
- `)` - non-capturing group end

Comment: @Frode Akselsen: Does this fit your needs? Any questions?